# Tile Map geo.location field not present under GeoHash aggregation in Kibana 4.0.1

Tags: visualization, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I'm trying to get a tile map visualization working in Kibana 4.0.1.

I can see the `geoip.location` data in the Discover section but when I go to Visualize it as a Tile Map, I select `Geo Coordinates` bucket type, then aggregation type `GeoHash`, then when I go to `Field` it's blank.

- Kibana 4.0.1
- Logstash 1.4.2-1-2c0f5a1
- Elasticsearch 1.4.4
- Running on Debian 7 64bit

Here's my logstash config:

```
    input {
    udp {
      port => 5514
      type => cisco
    }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "\<%{NUMBER:num}\>%{NUMBER:seq}: \*%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:date}: \%SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGP: list Internet\-In\-%{WORD:acl_ver} denied %{WORD:protocol} %{IP:src}\(%{NUMBER:sport}\) \-\> %{IP:dest}\(%{NUMBER:dport}\), %{INT:hitcnt}" }
    add_tag => ["grok_match", "cisco_acl_message"]
    remove_field => [ "message" ]
  }
  geoip {
   source => "src"
   target => "geoip"
   add_tag => ["geoip"]
   database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
 }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { 
    host => localhost
    index => [ "firewall-%{+YYYY.MM.DD}" ]
  }
}
```

And this is an example of a log record:

```
{
  "_index": "firewall-2015.04.105",
  "_type": "cisco",
  "_id": "dJhGF6RtQuGXtlBTRCu2mQ",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-04-15T21:06:08.357Z",
    "type": "cisco",
    "host": "172.17.10.1",
    "num": "190",
    "seq": "1872",
    "date": "Apr 15 21:08:05.878",
    "acl_ver": "20150223",
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "src": "94.102.51.96",
    "sport": "26820",
    "dest": "12.34.56.78",
    "dport": "5900",
    "hitcnt": "1",
    "tags": [
      "grok_match",
      "cisco_acl_message",
      "geoip",
      "_grokparsefailure",
      "geoip"
    ],
    "geoip": {
      "ip": "94.102.51.96",
      "country_code2": "NL",
      "country_code3": "NLD",
      "country_name": "Netherlands",
      "continent_code": "EU",
      "region_name": "07",
      "city_name": "Amsterdam",
      "postal_code": "1000",
      "latitude": 52.349999999999994,
      "longitude": 4.916699999999992,
      "timezone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
      "real_region_name": "Noord-Holland",
      "location": [
        4.916699999999992,
        52.349999999999994
      ],
      "coordinates": [
        4.916699999999992,
        52.349999999999994
      ]
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1429131968357
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1429131968357
  ]
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

**ANSWER**

After Alain pointed me in the right direction I started looking at field mappings. Here's how I went about it:

First I checked the `geoip` field type (my index is called `firewall*`)

```
curl http://localhost:9200/firewall*/_mapping/cisco/field/geoip.location?pretty
```

This came back with:

```
{
  "firewall-2015.04.107" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "cisco" : {
        "geoip.location" : {
          "full_name" : "geoip.location",
          "mapping":{"location":{"type":"float"}}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `float` type location is why I can't add a tile map visualization. I need to change this to `geo_point`.

After loads of digging I found one way to change the mapping of the `location` type to `geo_point` was to use an output template. I copied the default `elasticsearch_templte.json` file from

```
/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json
```

to

```
   /etc/logstash/templates/elasticsearch-firewall.json
```

Edit it and change the template from `logstash*` to `firewall*` (or whatever your index name pattern is)
      `"template" : "firewall*"`,

Edit the logstash config file and change the output to this:

```
output {
  elasticsearch { 
    host => localhost
    index => [ "firewall-%{+YYYY.MM.DD}" ]
    template => "/etc/logstash/templates/elasticsearch-firewall.json"
    template_name => "firewall"

  }
}
```

Delete the `firewall*` index.

**WARNING: This will delete all of your existing searchable data! If this data is important you'll need to find a way to dynamically change your field type without deleting the index. I've seen mention of this in google searches so I know it's possible.**

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/firewall*
```

I restarted logstash and elasticsearch after this.

Once I started receiving logs again I checked the mapping again

```
 curl http://localhost:9200/firewall*/_mapping/cisco/field/geoip.location?pretty
{
  "firewall-2015.04.107" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "cisco" : {
        "geoip.location" : {
          "full_name" : "geoip.location",
          "mapping":{"location":{"type":"geo_point"}}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See how the location type is now `geo_point` :-)

Now I can add a Tile Map visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kibana is using the mapping of the field to determine if it's a geo_point and therefore can be used in the map.

So, you should check your mapping and change the field to a geo_point.

See [the doc](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/mapping-intro.html#mapping-intro).

Comment: It was mapping the field as a "Float" rather than a geo_point.  I think this happened because the default `elasticsearch_template.json` template only applies to `logstash*` indices where mine was named `firewall*`.

Comment: I've added a custom template for `firewall*` and recreated the index, and now the mapping is `"location":{"type":"geo_point"}`. Thanks for the pointer :-)

Answer (score 0):

just want to extract some useful information to a separate answer - maybe it'll be useful to someone.

Logstash elasticsearch [template](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json#L2) matches only templates with "logstash-" prefix. That's why geoip.location field is double, not geo_point, when you use a different index name (like firewall*) without your custom template.

check this issue, if you need more information - https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3137