# Unable to show location in tile map of kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I am using Elasticsearch-1.5.1, Kibana-4.0.2-linux-x86, Logstash-1.4.2.
My **logstash conf** is like this

```html
input{
    redis{
        data_type=>'list'
  key=>'pace'
  password=>'bhushan'
  type=>pace
    }
}filter {
 geoip {
  source => "mdc.ip"
  target => "geoip"
  database => "/opt/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat"
  add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
  add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
 }
}

output{
    if[type]=="pace"{
        elasticsearch{
           template_overwrite => true
           host=>localhost
   index=>'pace'
   template => "/opt/logstash-1.4.2/mytemplates/elasticsearch-template.json"
   template_name => "bhushan"
        }
    }
 
 stdout{
        codec=>rubydebug
    }
}
```

My **elasticsearch-template.json** is

```html
{
  "template" : "bhushan",
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
       "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
       "dynamic_templates" : [ {
         "string_fields" : {
           "match" : "*",
           "match_mapping_type" : "string",
           "mapping" : {
             "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
               "fields" : {
                 "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
               }
           }
         }
       } ],
       "properties" : {
         "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
         "geoip"  : {
           "type" : "object",
             "dynamic": true
             "properties" : {
               "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
             }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

When i do url *curl http://localhost:9200/pace/_mapping/pace/field/geoip.location?pretty*

```
{
  "pace" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "pace" : {
        "geoip.location" : {
          "full_name" : "geoip.location",
          "mapping" : {
            "location" : {
              "type" : "double"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example of log record is like

```
{
    "thread_name" => "main",
         "mdc.ip" => "14.X.X.X",
        "message" => "Hii, I m in info",
     "@timestamp" => "2015-05-15T10:18:32.904+05:30",
          "level" => "INFO",
           "file" => "Test.java",
          "class" => "the.bhushan.log.test.Test",
    "line_number" => "15",
    "logger_name" => "bhushan",
         "method" => "main",
       "@version" => "1",
           "type" => "pace",
          "geoip" => {
                      "ip" => "14.X.X.X",
           "country_code2" => "IN",
           "country_code3" => "IND",
            "country_name" => "India",
          "continent_code" => "AS",
             "region_name" => "16",
               "city_name" => "Mumbai",
                "latitude" => 18.974999999999994,
               "longitude" => 72.82579999999999,
                "timezone" => "Asia/Calcutta",
        "real_region_name" => "Maharashtra",
                "location" => [
            [0] 72.82579999999999,
            [1] 18.974999999999994
        ],
             "coordinates" => [
            [0] "72.82579999999999",
            [1] "18.974999999999994"
        ]
    }
}
```

I thought my problem was same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661372/tile-map-geo-location-field-not-present-under-geohash-aggregation-in-kibana-4-0), so I did everything mention in that link like deleting all old index and restarting of LS and ES but no luck.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logstash filter is storing the coordinates in the field `geoip.coordinates`, however in your `elasticsearch-template.json` mapping the field is called `geoip.location`. This shows up in your sample log record where you can see the two fields `location` and `coordinates` in the `geoip` sub-object.

I think if you change this in your logstash filter, you might be good:

From this

```
add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
```

To this

```
add_field => [ "[geoip][location]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
add_field => [ "[geoip][location]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
```

**UPDATES**

1. The two `add_field` directives in the `geoip` filter can be removed as they are unnecessary
2. `"path": "full"` can be removed as it's been deprecated since ES v1.0
3. The template name should be `pace` instead of `bushan`, i.e. the name of the index where the log records are stored.

Comment: Thanks @Val for help, but it didn't work. After making changes suggested by you, my log record changed a bit
    "geoip" => {
                    "location" => [
                [0] 72.82579999999999,
                [1] 18.974999999999994,
                [2] "72.82579999999999",
                [3] "18.974999999999994"
            ]
        }
Any clue ?

Comment: Oh, actually, you don't need to use the `add_field` directives in the geoip filter, since the latter adds a `[geoip][location]` field automatically.

Comment: Right, I removed `add_field` from filter and it added `[geoip][location]` field . But unfortunately its data type is still `double`.

Comment: There's a strong similarity to [this recent change](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/commit/3b8920864ed09793a79bdb54ae1856d948a3a20c). Can you try to remove `"path": "full"` in your template (as it was [deprecated in ES 1.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html#_path_4)) and try again?

Comment: Actually, your template name should be `pace` and not `bhushan`, i.e. it should be your index name or a pattern identifying the index name(s) to which the template shall apply. You probably need to wipe your existing index and rebuild it.

Comment: Finally it works @val. It means template name should match to index name. Right ?

Comment: Awesome! Yes [that's correct](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html). The template will be used (and mapping applied) for any new index created whose name matches the `template` property of your template. In your case, the template was only applied when a new index with the name `bhushan` was created, which was never.